# How to get at the cargo registry / src directory in a cross-platform way?

Tags: rust, cross-platform, rust-cargo

On Linux, this is at `$HOME/.cargo/registry`, which has a subdirectory called `src/`. Is there a way to find this directory that will also work on Windows and MacOS?

Comment: First question, why? You should not mess with that directory. Second, I would suggest looking at the cargo source, because they have to handle that in any way.

Comment: I might want to write a tool to clean out outdated crate sources, because my hard disk space is unfortunately limited.

Comment: That's a neat idea! I think the best you could do is to look at the sources. But I'm note sure, if you just can delete them, there might be a local "database" which crates has been downloaded. Interesting nevertheless

Comment: That's what I currently do, but I'm not happy with that as it means I'll have to redownload all the crates again, and I often code Rust on the train where connectivity is spotty.